# How to properly access record with dynamic keys in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

[image]

I am trying to query an array in `Vuex` store where product_id equals a dynamic value like in the below code but it returns undefined.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: {}, 
    },
    getters: {
        getProductById:(state) => (id) => {
        return state.products.find(product => product.data.product_id == id)
       },
    }
}
```

In **`component.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div> {{price}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'someName',
    //props: ['orders'],
    data(){
        return{
           price: '',
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.price = this.$store.getters.getProductByProductId(1)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property that returns a function with `id` as parameter which returns the getter :

```
<template>
  <div> {{price}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'someName',
    //props: ['orders'],
    data(){
        return{
           price: '',
        }
    },
   computed:{
      productById(){
       return (id)=>this.$store.getters.getProductByProductId(id)
     }
   },
    mounted(){
        this.price = productById(1).price
    }
  }
</script>
```